# Is there any script handler to show pop up screen(jsp/html) page on lock or screen saver mode

Tags: javascript

I have a parent page and it populate a pop up screen if there any message, its working fine but my case is, I want to display the pop up in front of the screen when the systems is in screen saver mode and lock screen mode.Is there any script handler to handle this.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this if the screen is locked? When a user locks their screen they expect that nobody will be able to see what they were working on - I would not use a webpage or application that tried to circumvent this security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

From what I can tell, you want to be able to send the user an alert regardless of what they have open (screensaver/lock). This isn't going to be possible from the web browser without some sort of plugin installed.

You may be able to trigger an audio alert to sound when the screen saver/lock screen are on, but that is just a guess! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the replay,but already i have done audio alert tone for notification, since my application is running in high sensitive area they need this kind of handling.Please update me if any possible

Answer (score 0):

Screen saver and lock screen mode are operating system's property, i dont think there will be any direct method to detect them.

Workaround would be take a "general" time of screen saver display and detect if there was no user activity in that time then display the message